# Why does my bake have problems [.blend file attached]?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

Problems with bake **from highpoly to lowpoly**:
[image]

highpoly model: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cb66WKN5wd6q1DfeOgNhLT7ThXan4U7S/view?usp=sharing

lowpoly model: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gbvlZ_hFGzJ_kWmYMeB-lktsIdRGBfJJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for providing files, but I don't think you gave enough information for people to help. What question do you want answered? What did you expect and what did you get? What did you try?

Comment: It would help if you could provide the blend file with the exact baking settings and the info on how you baked it and what is wrong with the baked normal. The FBX models consist of separate meshes and their own UV maps (stacked islands).